# HiveQL: Parse strings and count

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I am using HiveQL to work with millions of rows of domain name text data stored in HDFS. The following is a hand-selected subset to illustrate lexical diversity. There are duplicate entries.

```
dnsvm.mgmtsubnet.mgmtvcn.oraclevcn.com.
mgmtsubnet.mgmtvcn.oraclevcn.com.
asdf.mgmtvcn.oraclevcn.com.
dnsvm.mgmtsubnet.mgmtvcn.oraclevcn.com.
localhost.
a.localhost.
img.pulsemgr.com.
36.136.154.156.in-addr.arpa.
accounts.spotify.com.
_dmarc.ixia-devops.com.
&eventtype=close&reason=4&duration=35.
&eventtype=close&reason=3&duration=10336.
```

I am trying to get a count of # of rows based on the last two levels of the domain, where sometimes the 2nd level is absent (i.e. `localhost.`). For example:

```
domain_root     count
oraclevcn.com.  4
localhost.      1
a.localhost.    1
pulsemgr.com.   1
in-addr.arpa.   1
spotify.com.    1
ixia-devops.com 1
```

It would be nice to also see how to filter out domains 2nd level is absent.

I am not sure where to start. I have seen use of the `SPLIT()` function, but that may not be robust since there could be many levels to a domain name, for example: a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i etc.

Any ideas are implementations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below would be the query with regexp_extract.

```
select domain_root, count(*) from (select regexp_extract('dnsvm.mgmtsubnet.mgmtvcn.oraclevcn.com.', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.$', 0) as domain_root from table) A group by A.domain_root -- replace first argument with column name
```

regex will extract for domain root with Alphanumeric and special character '-'

hope this helps.